# Firestore - How create DocumentReference using path String

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase realtime database allowed to create refrence using

```
 var reference = db.ref(path);
```

Is there any method exist in firestore so that I can create document refrence using path String.

If method exists how can I find path string in android and then how create document reference in node.js using that path.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this also in Cloud Firestore. So these are your options:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
```

First option:

```
DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("company/users");
```

Second option:

```
DocumentReference userRef = db.document("company/users");
```

Third option:

```
DocumentReference userRef = db.collection("company").document("users");
```

Comment: This isn't true.  You can pass a path to FirebaseFirestore.document().

Comment: The path can contain any number of collections and subcollections.

Comment: @DougStevenson Right, but you cannot pass a path to the `collection` method, only to the document, right?

Comment: I don't think that's what the OP is asking.  But the documentation for collection() suggests that it also can take a path.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#collection(java.lang.String)

Comment: @DougStevenson Edited my answer accordingly. Thanks again!

Comment: I think variable name for FirebaseFirestore should be like db or firestore because rootRef is little confusing because it is object of databse not refrence.

Comment: Just changed the `rootRef ` to `db`, not to be confused.

Answer (score 4):

For web/javascript, db.doc() will create a DocumentReference from a string:

`let docRef = db.doc(pathString)`

e.g. `let userRef = db.doc('users/' + userId)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FirebaseFirestore.document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestore.html#document(java.lang.String)) and pass it the path of the document you want. Each document must be located within a collection. If you're looking for a document called `documentId` in a collection called `collectionId`, the path string will be `collectionId/documentId`.

Comment: Thanks but I think you are not complete right, I tried in android studio there is no direct method FirebaseFirestore.document() first I have to create object of firestore then can call method.....Please edit your answer so that i can accept it

Comment: When I say `FirebaseFirestore.document()`, I mean the method called `document()` on an object of type `FirebaseFirestore`.  You can get an object of type `FirebaseFirestore` by calling `FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()`.

Comment: `document()` is not a static method and in order to be able to call it, you need to create an object of the class first. `FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();`.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to define the path :

```
`users/${type}/${user.uid}/`
```

---

```
firestore
  .collection(`users/${type}/${user.uid}/`)
  .add(documentData)
  .then(function () {
    message = { message: "document added", type: ErrorType.success };
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    message = { message: error, type: ErrorType.error };
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

For Firestore web version 9 (after August 25, 2021) you can use doc() to generate a reference with an id:

```
import { collection, doc, setDoc, getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"; 

// Add a new document with a generated id
const newRef = doc(collection(getFirestore(), "user"));

const data = {
  id: newRef.id,
  firstName: 'John',
  lastName: 'Doe'
}

await setDoc(newRef, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "." instead of "/" for path

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

db.collection(FBConstant.Product.Head)
.whereEqualTo("rating.$id", true)
```

Answer (score 0):

In android (Kotlin) you can achieve this as below :

```
val firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val docRef = firestore.document(documentPath) as DocumentReference
```

My Collection Name is : Collection 1
So In mycase, documentPath is having value as : "Collection 1/Document ID"

While fetching the data you can use as

```
firestore.collection("Collection 1")
.whereEqualTo("Field name",docRef)
.get()
.addOnCompleteListener{...}
```